# Client-side PDF generation from XML and XSL-FO?

Tags: pdf, client, webclient, offline, xsl-fo

Is there any browser-based client-side PDF generation tool that takes XML data and an XSL-FO file and generates a corresponding PDF file?

To clarify "Client" I mean a web-client/web-browser.  Basically, a user should be able to go to a web page on a major browser on either a desktop or mobile platform (meaning flash and Java and other such add-ons are prohibited), have some data that they work with locally, and then be able to generate a PDF based on that data without installing an additional application.

Personally, I think such a tool would be awesome, and I know I'm not alone because [at least 542 other people think so too](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/?p=306)!  :)

However, from my research I have not yet found a single client-side solution, paid or unpaid, that does this.  Most client-side PDF generation tools seem to be in their infancy, require custom code to generate the PDF, require flash, and/or overlook XSL-FO entirely.

Also, I was thinking maybe this could be done in an applet using existing XSL-FO to PDF tools, but then many mobile devices ([Ipad for one](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/robogeek/archive/2010/02/03/ipad-flash-kerfluffle-applets-and-javafx)) do not allow java applets, and mobile devices are one of the main reasons why offline PDF generation would be so nice in the first place!

I suppose I could write a "Conforming Writer" based on the [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502) PDF standard and the [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), but that seems like overkill unless I decide I want to go into the PDF generation business...

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to use [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) to develop your own client in Java.

You can take a look at [these examples](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/embedding.html#examples), I think they do exactly what you need (without a GUI).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm looking for a platform-independent browser-based solution, not to build my own client.  I've now clarified the question, so sorry if there was confusion before.